# Can't put a node.js breakpoint inside module when using WebStorm or IntelliJ

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

IntelliJ 12 - Can't put break point in Node.js in sub function that's part of a library

Please see this image: http://www.digitalsignage.com/temp/intellibug.png

You can see that the break point is stopping outside the function and not inside the included Asyn library (which is the most common node.js librray) ... this happens for all libraries, like ps (postgres) so we can't debug inside included module node.js libraries...

The only work around is to put the special keyword: debugger; and debugger will stop, but that is impossible to work with since if you are inside a long for loop, you can't exit the debugger and have to F9 through all iterations, unless you remove the keyword debugger; and start debugging again, no fun :(

Anyone knows a fix?

Regards,

Sean.

Comment: You will get help at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8573 .

Comment: ya posted there as well... will see...